# Can SUMO choose best paths for cars automatically?

Tags: simulation, sumo

how can I automatically select the best paths for a car in a manually created network in SUMO with edges and nodes.
I have created a network manually with 15 nodes
and Edges. The cars that I have drive simultaneously when departing. How can SUMO automatically choose the best paths for these cars.

I'm new to SUMO found something about "darouter" if that gets me to my goal.

Comment: I have created the nodes and edges tables in Excel and used Fonction " CONNECT" to have the program in XML

Comment: I've removed the [excel] and [xml] tags because they do not apply here.  I've removed [edg] because it's a typo of [edge], but [edge] is too generic to be of any value here either.

Comment: I use Excel in simplifying the work when i need to change numbers or formulas then i copy from Excel to XML.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly depends on your definition of "best" but if you mean the path with the smallest travel time, then this is what sumo automatically does if you give it trips (only start and end edge) as input.